# If-else statement Issue in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

In my below mentioned MVC Code there is some MVC Syntax issue. Can please someone assist to fix code issue

If-else block.

```
<select id="VIPGuests" name="VIPGuests" style="width:200px" abindex="0"><option value="">Select VIP</option>
<%   foreach (var authorizedGuest in Model.XYZ)
{ %>
    <%if(Model.VIPGuests == authorizedGuest.Key )%>
    {

        <option selected="selected" value=<% = authorizedGuest.Key%>> <% = authorizedGuest.Value%> </option>
    }
    else
    {

        <option value=<% = authorizedGuest.Key%>> <% = authorizedGuest.Value%> </option>
    }
<%} %>
</select>
```

I am getting issue as

> Text is not allowed between opening and closing tags of Element
>   'Select'

Comment: What mvc version you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. All server side code put with in <% %>.

```
<select id="VIPGuests" name="VIPGuests" style="width:200px" tabindex="0"><option value="">Select VIP</option>
                      <%   foreach (var authorizedGuest in Model.XYZ)
                { 
                              if(Model.VIPGuests == authorizedGuest.Key )
                            {%>

                      <option selected="selected" value=<% = authorizedGuest.Key%>> <% = authorizedGuest.Value%> </option>
                           <% }
                            else
                            { %>

                      <option value=<% = authorizedGuest.Key%>> <% = authorizedGuest.Value%> </option>
                <%            }
                } %>
                </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't test it but something inline with this should work

```
<select id="VIPGuests" name="VIPGuests" style="width:200px" tabindex="0"><option value="">Select VIP</option>
@{ 
  foreach (var authorizedGuest in Model.XYZ)
     if(Model.VIPGuests == authorizedGuest.Key )
         @:<option selected="selected" value=“@authorizedGuest.Key”> @authorizedGuest.Value </option>               
     else
         @:<option value=“@authorizedGuest.Key”>@authorizedGuest.Value </option>
}
</select>
```